# Java: parseByte to a byte and vice versa return different values

Tags: java, parsing, binary, byte

When i use

```
small =Byte.parseByte("01101001",2)
```

and then use this:

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(small & 0xFF);
binarynumber= Integer.parseInt(binary);
```

they give different values. binary number = 1101001

what happened to the leading 0?

-edit-
i think i figured it out, thanks for all the responses!

Comment: Integers always have their leading 0s removed. 4 == 00000000000004, but is represented as 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should there be a leading zero? How would you expect differing results for `Byte.parseByte("01101001",2)` and `Byte.parseByte("1101001",2)`? Both return the same `byte`.

The same applies to `Integer.parseInt()`.

If you want to have leading zeroes in your output, you have to use a format string.

Answer (score 0):

[Integer#parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

always returns an `Integer` i.e decimal representation, which never have leading zeros.

> Returns an Integer object holding the value extracted from the
>   specified String when parsed with the radix given by the second
>   argument. The first argument is interpreted as representing a signed
>   integer in the radix specified by the second argument, exactly as if
>   the arguments were given to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int)
>   method. The result is an Integer object that represents the integer
>   value specified by the string.